# Finding the sum of the three roots of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials, cubics

Without solving the corresponding equation, find the sum of the three roots of the polynomial

$$2x^3 − 8x^2 + 20x − 19$$

I know that sum of the roots is $-b/a$ which is $-(-8)/2 = 4$ however I'm not confident in my answer because it seems to simple, could anyone please help explain.

note: still new to this not too sure how to format polynomials correctly if anyone could help with that as well

Comment: Yes. You may wonder where the result comes from. By some theorems, a cubic polynomial with leading coefficient $a$ factors as $a(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)$ where $r, s, t$ are the roots. The formula you're using comes from expanding this factored form and comparing the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion (which turns out to be $-a(r+s+t)$ with the coefficient of $x^2$ in the given form (which you've denoted as $b$).  $-a(r+s+t)=b$ implies $r+s+t=-b/a$.

Comment: These formulas are known as [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ the complex roots. Then the factorization of $p$ is

$p=2(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=2x^3-2(a+b+c)x^2+2(ab+bc+ac)x-2abc$.